# The android studio changes the background of button

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Floating Action Button. I want to get the same "plus" button as in google design, however, when I import the "add_white" icon from material design studio and put it into project, it is redefined to have black background which completely distorts the effect.

I show on the attached picture how the problem looks like - the image in all possible dimensions is correctly inserted in the folder, however, the android studio reads it differently.

[image: ImageSituation]

Thank you in advance,
Grzegorz

How to fix it/ or just get the proper "cross/plus" sign to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to download the icon in svg format from https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_add, you can add it to Android Studio by doing a right-click on the project and selecting Vector assets, you'll be able to remove your 5 ic_apps_white_48 pngs and use the one imported.

Comment: This works, although it doesnt' explain me the issue. Thank you anyways :)